# react - get width/height of image to process

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I was wondering how to get the height and width of an image if I'm rendering it react style so I can process it to flip it to portrait mode if the width is larger than the height.

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/k9kwv0kp93

Example code:

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Hello from './Hello';

const styles = {
  fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
  textAlign: 'center',
};

const App = () => (
  <div style={styles}>
    <Hello name="CodeSandbox" />
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen {'\u2728'}</h2>
  </div>
);

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Hello.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Hello extends Component
{
  constructor()
  {
    super();
    this.state = {img: null}

    this.get_image = this.get_image.bind(this);
  }

  get_image() 
  {
    let img = <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" />;
    //manipulate here maybe
    this.setState({
      img
    })
  }

  render()
  {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.get_image}>Click me</button>
        test
        {this.state.img}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> React supports a special attribute that you can attach to any component. The ref attribute takes a callback function, and the callback will be executed immediately after the component is mounted or unmounted.
>
> When the ref attribute is used on an HTML element, the ref callback receives the underlying DOM element as its argument

Taken from: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  handleSize(image) {
    console.log(image.offsetWidth, image.offsetHeight)
  }

  render() {
    return React.createElement("img", {
      src: "http://cdn.collider.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/narcos-season-2-image-5.jpg",
      ref: image => {
        this.handleSize(image);
      },
      onLoad=(image)=>this.handleSize(image);
    });
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(MyComponent, null), document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 133px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-with-addons.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: around the right idea, but it's returning 0 for both height and width. Tried to add an onLoad to it too but it didn't change the results :S

Comment: Please share your attempts

Comment: I might rename the question since it's more about onload.

Comment: I've updated the answer to real implementation. React will execute ref callback immediately after the component is mounted, so no need for onLoad on the image itself

Comment: why is the `offsetHeight` 0 though?

Comment: Because of css, when height is `auto` you can't get the offsetHeight of the element. I've changed the example, and put fixed height on the image.

Comment: I worked out why it was showing `0 0` on my side, it's because I'm actually passing the image to another component, so I think it loses track of it or something. Going to refactor my code with this in mind, thanks.

Comment: A workaround is to do: `const height = image.width / image.naturalWidth * image.naturalHeight`

Answer (score 20):

I encountered the same issue, I was able to get the `img` height and width using `ref` and `onLoad()`.

---

#### Class component version (with 'old' ref usage):

```
render() {
   return (
     <img
        src='https://via.placeholder.com/150'
        ref={el => this.imgEl = el}
        onLoad={() => console.log(this.imgEl.naturalHeight)} // print 150
     /> 
  )
}
```

---

#### Class component version (with 'new' ref):

```
import * as React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  imgEl = React.createRef();

  render() {
    return (
      <img
        src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
        ref={this.imgEl}
        onLoad={() => console.log(this.imgEl.current.naturalHeight)} // print 150
      />
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

---

#### Functional component version:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function App() {
  const imgElement = React.useRef(null);

  return (
    <img
      src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"
      ref={imgElement}
      onLoad={() => console.log(imgElement.current.naturalHeight)} // print 150
    />
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

---

Also you should use [img.naturalHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement)

Comment: I believe the correct `ref` is `ref={el => this.imgEl = el}`

Comment: @PedroVieira This is exactly what i wrote :) Did you mean something else ? I didn't update my answer with the new Ref usage ( https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html ). I will soon post an update version !

Comment: @PierreFerry before I edited it was written this way: ` ref={el = this.imgEl = el}` it was missing the `>`. Let me know when you upgrade it, would like to see it!

Comment: @PedroVieira Oh i see ! Thanks a lot ! I just updated the answer with new code snippets. Feel free to correct anyone of them :)

Comment: what if you don't want the natural height (which equals to the intrinsic height), but you want a height defined let's say by a CMS -  is there any other way?